# Combine two files using dos "copy" func

Tags: merge, copy, dos

I want to combine 2 text files into one using copy function

1st txt

```
Results =
```

2nd txt

```
Fine
```

So i'm trying to copy it like this:

```
copy 1.txt + 2.txt
```

or

```
copy /A 1.txt + 2.txt
```

or

```
copy /B 1.txt + 2.txt
```

But result are always same:

```
Results = 
Fine
```

I've checked this file in HEX and beetwen them are always added 0x0D 0x0A

But i need it in this format:

```
Results = Fine
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Is there always exactly *one* line in each file?

Comment: Yes - only 1 line per file

Comment: Ok - partially solved - new line is generated by "echo" command  (first file is generated:  echo Results =  > 1.txt ). But how to generate it without new line?

Comment: I don't think there is an elegant way to direct the output to a file without it appending the new line characters.  See my answer below to see how to eliminate the new line characters when you combine the two files.

Answer (score 0):

If there is always exactly one line in each of the two text files, then you can achieve what you want with this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (1.txt) do set line1=%%i
for /f "delims=" %%i in (2.txt) do set line2=%%i
echo %line1%%line2%>3.txt
```

The `copy /b` command should have worked, but your `1.txt` file must have had a 0x0D 0x0A after `Result =`.  So it was streamed to the new file.  Using the above commands will disregard the 0x0D 0x0A at the end of each file and combine just the text from the last line with text from both files.  This is why both files should only contain the *one* line of text...

Answer (score 0):

@Jamel L. Thank you works ike a charm :)

```
@echo off
echo ContentID = > package.conf
for /f "delims=" %%i in (package.conf) do set line1=%%i
for /f "delims=" %%i in (CID.txt) do set line2=%%i
echo %line1%%line2%>package.conf
echo Klicensee = 0x2A6AFBCF43D1579F7D738741A13BD42E>> package.conf
echo DRMType = Free>> package.conf
echo ContentType = minis>> package.conf
echo PackageVersion = 01.00>> package.conf
```

Output file:

```
ContentID = UP4306-NPUZ00210_00-MADBLOCKERALPHA1
Klicensee = 0x2A6AFBCF43D1579F7D738741A13BD42E
DRMType = Free
ContentType = minis
PackageVersion = 01.00
```

With new line at eof but it can be there :)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a basic function of DOS. The DOS 'COPY' command copy function will give the result required. The simplest way is

copy *.txt combo.txt
use the DOS 'TYPEE' comand  type combo.txt gives the desired result " Results = Fine"

Comment: You are right (and that's exactly, what the asker did). The problem was to remove the line feed (already contained in the first file)